# How do you do Impersonation in .NET with IIS context?

Tags: .net, iis, impersonation

I used to run an own app in an IIS ApplicationPool which needs to have access to a forgein server to access files. (Remote load and copy local files to deliver over the net) 
My approach was to

```
If LogonUser(m_username, m_domain, m_password, LOGINTYPE, LOGON32_TYPE_NEW_CREDENTIALS, windowsToken) <> 0 Then
...
```

To switch / widen uer rights to remote server. And start copying files.
This works as long as I am running it in a debugger / self hosting exe.
Whenever I try to deploy the dlls to IIS and run it there I have again no access to the remote file server.

I also played with the different other LOGIN-Types (NETWORK,BATCH..) but then a new problem rises: I have access to remote server, but no access to own local machine. (Remote user has no local rights).

Has anyone an idea? My be this a IIS specific issue?

Comment: what problem are you having? its not clear from your post. you are using Win32 API to login/impersonate as a user to essentially do things that the user account allows them to do so. The user account needs access to the remote directory/files and if it doesn't have it then of course it will fail. Alternatively, you can set the Windows impersonation to true in your config file and enable Windows Authentication in IIS so it will use your user account on the website (or anyone who goes to the website) - ideal for internal orgs most of the time

Comment: I am using win32 functions to do access a remote file share. In my case this is a web service.
My exact problem is that this works in debug-mode when running as a self-hosted .exe and will not in IIS as part of a applicationPool.
Playing around with the different LOGIN-Types only lead to the problem that I totally change the current user context and am not able to copy a file from remote to local.

Comment: What exact error do you get when trying to copy the files? Show the code you are using when attempting to copy files...

Comment: A very stripped sample code: 
 If LogonUser(m_username, m_domain, m_password, LOGON32_TYPE_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, windowsToken) <> 0 Then
     wid_admin = New WindowsIdentity(windowsToken)
     windowsContext = wid_admin.Impersonate()
endif 
And at least: 
 IO.File.Copy(storagePath, localPath, True)
with 
storagePath ="\\servername\files\vaults\2014_000\00041842.PNG"  and
LocalPath = <some local useres temp Folder>

Comment: does the server hosting the website have access to <some local users temp Folder> ??

Comment: Yes. This is a local folder fetched with System.io.path.gettempfolder. Only if I Chance logintype to other than "newcredentials" User Switch can not access this local folder.

Comment: That Win32 API requires the application pool account to have necessary permissions. What is the pool identity you use now?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: Just someting like: "Access to the path 'remotePath' is denied"

Comment: Right, therefore its a permissions issue. grant the folder the correct permissions for the user account to access. And as Lex Li pointed it, it also depends on the app pool user account being used.